# Is there anyway to make this function better for my module?

Tags: module, lua

I've been recently messing around with **modules** and I wanted to know if there's anyway to make this calculate function any better?

```lua
function Library.calc(arg1,arg2,option)
  local options = {
    [1] = "add",
    [2] = "sub",
    [3] = "mul",
    [4] = "div"
  }
  if option == options[1] then
      print(arg1+arg2)
  end
  if option == options[2] then
    print(arg1-arg2)
  end
  if option == options[3] then
      print(arg1*arg2)
  end
  if option == options[4] then
      print(arg1/arg2)
  end
end
```

Comment: I feel this question needs more focus, or would be better suited for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you do not have a specific problem/goal the question is too open ended for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be migrated to Code Review SE, as Nifim pointed out.

```
local options = {
  add = function (x,y) return x+y end,
  sub = function (x,y) return x-y end,
  mul = function (x,y) return x*y end,
  div = function (x,y) return x/y end,
}

function Library.calc(arg1,arg2,option)
  print(assert(options[option], "Unknown option")(arg1, arg2))
end
```

Comment: I don't know how to migrate the topic but thanks!

Comment: That phrase was for moderators.